# Unable to connect to database having unicode name

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, python-unicode, pymssql

I was trying to connect to one of my database using pymssql module in python having the name test_यूनिकोड_डेटाबेस_123. But I am getting an error while connection :

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-10: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Below is my code:

```
db_name = u'test_यूनिकोड_डेटाबेस_123'
```

`pymssql.connect(self.server, self.user, self.password, self.db_name, charset='utf8')`

I tried doing db_name.encode('utf8') but no luck. Then I included the charset='utf8' option to pymssql connect statement still haven't got any luck in connection. Can someone please help me?

Python version is 2.7 and SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your Python source file should contain the following if your source code file was saved as UTF-8:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

If not UTF-8, add the first line and resave the file as UTF-8. Reopen and make sure db_name is still displayed correctly.

For the parameter `charset`, the value is `UTF-8` and not `utf8`. I am not sure if the case matters but the documentation is uppercase.

Another option is to specify the encoding: `self.db_name.encode('UTF-8')`

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for you reply. I did everything but no luck with pymssql. It seems like a limitation of pymssql that we can't connect to unicoded database using this module.
I tried using pyodbc, the error is bit different there. It says : "Cannot open database <encoded db name> requested by login. The login failed". Can you please let me know if i missed something?

Comment: @SubodhAgnihotri re: pyodbc - Works fine for me with pyodbc 4.0.24 and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server under Python 2.7.14 on Windows. If you continue to have difficulties with pyodbc please ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Hi @GordThompson - Are you able to connect to unicode named database? If yes, can you please share the code you run? I tried everything but I haven't got any luck in connecting to the database with unicode chars.